# Why can't I call a method from my Python class?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and currently working with classes. I am trying to make a basic game to help learn it and am having a weird issue with calling methods 
from it. I have the `main.py` file which creates an instance from the class in the `Character.py` file.

This is the `Character.py` file:

```
class Character:  
    name=""  

    def __init__(Name):  
        name=Name  

    def getName():  
        return name
```

This is the `main.py` file:

```
from Character import *

player = Character("James")
print(player.getName())
```

I am not sure what the issue is. This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dstei\Documents\Python\It 102\Final Project\Main.py", line 
12, in <module>
    print(player.getName())
TypeError: getName() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

It is saying I am giving 1 positional argument but I don't see where I gave any. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have a class with instance methods, you need to include the first argument (`self` by convention) to refer to the current instance. Also, make sure to set the variable *as an instance variable* by using `self`, the current instance:

```
class Character:  
    def __init__(self, Name): #self is the current instance
        self.name=Name  #set the variable on the instance so that every instance of Character has a name

    def getName(self):  
        return self.name #refer to the name with the instance
```

Python internally passes the new instance of a class as the first argument to all the class methods, like `this` in languages such as Java. The error comes from the fact that Python passes the instance as the first argument internally but your getter is not defined to take an argument.

With the above code, when you call the method upon an instance, the instance is internally passed as the first argument and Python doesn't complain as you specify that it takes an argument, `self`, and `name` is set correctly on the instance.

---

Note: By convention, Python does not use camelCase, but underscores, so your getter should by convention look like this:

```
def get_name(self):
    #...
```

Also see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44297002/5647260) which explains why getters and setters aren't usually needed. Just get and modify the instance variable by using dot notation:

```
print(player.name) #get
player.name = "Jeff" #set
```

Comment: and the expert has spoken, good explanation, thanks for sharing, plus one

Comment: Thank you, for making a set method such as setName it would be this?  
def setName(newName):  
    self.name = newName

Comment: @D.Stei Every instance method should include self as its first argument: `def set_name(self, new_name): self.name = new_name`

Comment: Okay thank you very much Andrew. And the camel case is just habit from Java, I know I should use underscores.

Comment: While we're cleaning up the code we should talk about the line `from Character import *`. To cite the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided".

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, even instance method must be declared with an extra argument, typically named `self` (although that is a conventional, not a required, name).

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return name
```

However, Python does not have any kind of enforced visibility (such as public or private), so such trivial getters and setters aren't usually written. Documentation about which attributes you are "allowed" to modify are considered sufficient protection.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

c = Character("Bob")
print(c.name)  # instead of c.get_name()
c.name = "Charlie"  # instead of c.set_name("Charlie")
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I failed to mention this. +1

Comment: Well that is good to know, thank you. Does this work with lists as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to add the parameter self. `self` is an object reference to the object itself, therefore, they are same. Python methods are not called in the context of the object itself. self in Python may be used to deal with custom object models or

```
class Character:  

    def __init__(self,name):  
        self.name=name  

    def getName(self):  
        return self.name
```

To see why this parameter is needed, there are so good answers here:

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)